# Separating Data in Text File into Separate Lines

Tags: powershell, batch-file, format

I have an un-formatted text file that looks like this right now:
`LASTNAME` `FIRSTNAME` `PHONE NUMBER` `LASTNAME` `FIRSTNAME` `PHONE NUMBER` `LASTNAME` `FIRSTNAME` `PHONE NUMBER` `LASTNAME` `FIRSTNAME` `PHONE NUMBER`

that I would like to format as:

`LASTNAME` `FIRSTNAME` `PHONE NUMBER`

`LASTNAME` `FIRSTNAME` `PHONE NUMBER`

`LASTNAME` `FIRSTNAME` `PHONE NUMBER`

with each person on a new line. This is what I have tried (PowerShell):

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\output.txt")
$content -replace "(555) ***-**** ", "`n"
$content | Out-File .\test.txt
```

But it doesn't work. My idea is that since the phone number is at the end of the line, replace the last space with a carriage return. Most of the numbers have the same area code.

Would like a batch script or PowerShell script, but I guess I am open to third part programs if it would work better. The ultimate goal is to put each string into a organized spreadsheet.

Comment: 1. You should provide some examples of various cases. 2. You can not expect that regex to work if not **all** numbers have the same area code *(unless you want a solution that works most of the time)*. 3. `*` is a wildcard character in regex. You'r regex is not matching what you think it is and 4. You are replacing your entire match with a carriage return so in effect loosing the phone number in your result.

Comment: if the phone numbers always end in digits, and there are no digits in the names, then this alternative regex: `-replace '(?<=\d)\s', "\`n"` might work by replacing the (whitespace) after a digit. A space or tab or whatever it is. Your `(555)` is wrong because parentheses are a regex group operator, you need to escape them to match parentheses in the text. But an exact match would need some clearer example of what data you have.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - 1. All cases are `lastname` `first name` `phone number` 2. It's like 95% of the numbers, I can do the rest manually if need be. 3. I would like it to select any number, as the numbers vary after the area code. 4. Oh... I see. I'm working on it right now. Also I tried the code in the second comment, and it seems to work in the PowerShell Window, but not in the out-file. The phone #'s only have digits, the names never have digits.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, the text made from an OCR program, so the phone numbers do sometimes have question marks misrepresented as sevens.

Comment: Give an example of data...

Comment: If the OCR sometimes misreads `7` as `?`, then I would think it would also sometimes misread `5` as `S`.

Comment: And what about extensions? None of the phone numbers end with something like `ext 123`?

Comment: As well as mistaking `?` for `7`, surely the OCR can also see `O` or `Q` as `0`, `I` or `l` as `1`, `Z` as `2`, `S` as `5`, `G` as `6`, `B` or `g` as `8` and `g` or `q` as `9`!

Comment: @dbenham and @compo you are probably right, I have seen S's mistaken for 5's. @esperento57 an example would be `Smith John (555) 555-5555`. Also, the numbers don't end in extensions, none of them do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Get-Content '.\input.txt' -Raw) -replace '\(555\) \d{3}-\d{4}\s*', "`$0`r`n" | Out-File 'output.txt'
```